# Print another page using JavaScript from a page by clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html page with a button that allows printing of specific content with following code:

```
<div class="below_movie_left" id="printableArea">
My printing contents
</div>

<input type="button"  class="submit_button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="Print" style="float:right;" />

<script>
function printDiv(divName) {
     var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

     window.print();

     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
</script>
```

Well, it's printing my specific content perfectly.  But, now I want to print a another page using this button. Another page name is `finalprinting.php`

So now I want, when I press this **Print button** it's should be print `finalprinting.php` page instead of the existing contents of my page.

Comment: What's with opening the other page in a new Window using `var win = window.open()` and calling `win.print()`? Maybe printing a (possibly hidden using `position: absolute; left: -1000000px; ...`) `iframe` works too? This could be an option if you don't want to pop up a window. These two ideas were crossing my mind...

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know jQuery well I'll try to do it without it

```
function printDiv(divName){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    xmlhttp.open('GET', '/finalprinting.php', false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.body.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, Let me try with that.

Comment: it's not opening new page?

Comment: No, it's not opening a new page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX.

```
<input type="button" id="loadpage" value="Print">
<script>

document.getElementById( "loadpage" ).addEventListener( "click", function(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "finalprinting.php", true);

    request.onload = function(){
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400){
            // We got the data, now we can set the body's innerhtml
            document.body.innerHTML = request.responseText;
        } else {
            // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
        }
    };

    request.onerror = function() {
        // There was a connection error of some sort
    };

    request.send();
});
</script>
```

Comment: where I sue this code ? Is there any onClick event on the button ? Could you give me the html example ?

Comment: If you have an id for a button e.g. <input type="button" id="loadpage"> then you can add an evenlistener to that button like document.getElementById( "loadpage" ).addEventListener( "click", function(){ // the code above });

Comment: is it something like that> `<input type="button" id="loadpage" value="print this page"  onclick="document.getElementById( 'loadpage' ).addEventListener( 'click', function();" />` If so then it's first load the `finalprinting.php` page instead of index page.

Comment: No don't use onclick events. use the addEventListener inside the main script that you have directly before </body>

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in javascript/jquery so that I can't understand.

Comment: I edited the answer, should be easier to understand. :)

Comment: Thanks for your edit. But after click on the button it's redirect me to final page instead of print dialog box showing.

Comment: Check the url, before and after you click thebutton. It should be the same. That is, you're not redirected. If you want it to be showed inside your printdiv simply change the innerHTML line to document.getElementById( "printableArea" ).innerHTML = request.responseText;

Comment: Yes. It's showing the final page in same url. but I want to show the print dialog box after click on the button like my existing one.